# Selecting column with smallest value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with this structure:

**df_test**

```
V       |  A    | B   |  C      |  D
-10     |  nan  | nan |  nan    |  nan  
-9.9    |  10   | 1   |  -2200  |  100
-9.8    |  11   | 2   |  -2211  |  1
```

I would like to add a new column `minimum_difference` containing the column name with the smallest absolute value for that specific row (ignoring `V`), like this:

```
V       |  A    | B   |  C      |  D    | minimum_difference
-10     |  nan  | nan |  nan    |  nan  | nan
-9.9    |  10   | 1   |  -2200  |  100  | B
-9.8    |  11   | 2   |  -2211  |  1    | D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to skip the `V` column, and [`df.abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) to convert the dataframe's values to their absolute equivalents, and use [`df.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) with `axis=1` to find the index (which will be a column name) of the smallest (absolute) value:

```
df_test['minimum_difference'] = df_test.drop('V', axis=1).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      V     A    B       C      D minimum_difference
0 -10.0   NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN                NaN
1  -9.9  10.0  1.0 -2200.0  100.0                  B
2  -9.8  11.0  2.0 -2211.0    1.0                  D
```

Comment: This solution would not work when the column `V` has `NaN`.

Comment: But the OP specified to ignore the `V` column (ignoring `V`)...or am I misunderstanding them/you?

Comment: Ahh I saw that now. No worries. Anyhow, I thought of giving a more general solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a `row` contains `NaN`, then put `NaN`, otherwise calculate the `min` of the row and put the index.

```
In [101]: import numpy as np

In [102]: df['minimum_difference'] = np.where(df.isna().any(1), np.nan, df.abs().idxmin(1))

In [103]: df
Out[103]: 
      V     A    B       C      D minimum_difference
0 -10.0   NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN                NaN
1  -9.9  10.0  1.0 -2200.0  100.0                  B
2  -9.8  11.0  2.0 -2211.0    1.0                  D
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I am sharing Mayank's snippet with little update.

```
In [84]: df['minimum_difference'] = df.ix[:, 1:].abs().idxmin(1)

In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
      V     A    B       C      D minimum_difference
0 -10.0   NaN  NaN     NaN    NaN                  NaN
1  -9.9  10.0  1.0 -2200.0  100.0                  B
2  -9.8  11.0  2.0 -2211.0  200.0                  B
```

Comment: what is `ix`? where is that in the pandas docs?

Comment: @sammywemmy it was removed in pandas 1.0.0. :(